# WSO2 Application Server 5.1.0 - JSR356 Websockets API

Tags: tomcat, wso2, wso2-as

I have a requirement to build a web application using JSR356 Websockets API and deploy it in WSO2 Application Server.

It looks like WSO2 AS 5.1.0 does not support JSR356 Websockets out-of-the-box ([WSO2 AS 5.1.0 Features](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Features)).  It also looks like tomcat 7, WSO2's web container does not yet support Websockets API - [tomcat link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html).

Has anyone managed to get websockets running in WSO2 AS 5.1.0?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 AS 5.1.0 is based on Tomcat 7.0.34 version and it has some web socket  support. Please take a look on following samples to check whether are those fulfill your requirements https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.1.0/products/as/5.1.0/modules/samples/common/webapp/src/main/java/websocket/.

FYI above samples are available with  WSO2 AS 5.1.0 distribution.

Comment: Many Thanks!  After starting WSAS, I found the websocket examples at the URL: http://localhost:9763/example/websocket/